# Configure Flogger with log4j2 backend

Tags: log4j2

I try to use flogger with the log4j2 backend. Seems to work fine. 
My problem is, how to configure output pattern, output level or appenders in general using log4j files (xml or properties).
If using this constellation without any configuration, only level error is logged.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I missed to add log4j-web package, so everything was fine in a standalone app, but this package is needed in a web application